# ImportError: No module named lxml

Tags: python

I have python 2.7 installed as shown in this image from PyCharm. Django and other modules installed in 2.7.3, (the selected version in the image.)
  [image]

```
import lxml
```

shows the error

```
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

On

```
pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /home/sandeephar/lib/python2.7 (4.2.1)
```

What is the problem. Can you please suggest a solution.

Comment: You've got multiple versions of Python installed, of which the `lxml` module is not installed for the version you are using.

Comment: Yes, but how to correct this. How do i install for the version of Python I am using

Comment: You'll need to use the version of Python where it's installed, or use the pip for the version you are trying to use. Having multiple versions of Python scattered all over your system is not recommended. You should either install them in virtualenvs or use a package manager like MacPorts or Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to install pip for Python2, which can be done alongside the existing (now standard) pip3.
As of January 2022, the pip version for Python2 can be installed as follows:

```
sudo wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
sudo python2 get-pip.py
```

Then you can just run

```
pip2 install lxml
```

Comment: OP shows that they've already done this.

Comment: Not sure they do. One of the comments suggests a solution, but doesn't actually offer one. Unless I've misunderstood?

Comment: See the part of the question that says "Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /home/sandeephar/lib/python2.7 (4.2.1)"

Comment: Yes I can see that quite clearly, can you see the part in the clarification comment that asks,  'How do i install for the version of Python I am using?' That's the part I've answered.

Comment: The OP has clearly installed lxml into _one_ of their python 2.7 distributions. Your recommendation is to just install a new version of pip and install lxml into whichever python 2.7 distribution that newly-installed pip2 is associated with (likely the system python). It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes on closer inspection, I now see what you mean. Presumably my answer wouldn't solve the problem at all, as the questioner would still be told that lxml was already installed...probably shouldn't have posted the answer. I'll leave it in if you think I should, though obviously it answers a far more basic problem scenario.